# Android : Connect two strings with . And parse in the float

Tags: android, string, parsing, format

I am developing an app in which i took two Edit text whose input type is number.

**What I done is :** I took input from two edit text(ed1, ed2) in two string variables(s1, s2) as:

```
EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
String s1 = ed1.getText().toString();

EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
String s2 = ed2.getText().toString();
```

concate those two variable as :

```
String s3 = s1.concat(".").concat(s2);
```

And then I tried to parse these thired string variable(s3) in float as :

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(s3);
```

But i am getting error as :

```
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537): java.lang.NumberFormatException
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.initialParse(FloatingPointParser.java:160)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:319)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:362)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at com.example.myapp.activity.MyActivity.onClick(MyActivity.java:97)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
02-08 15:30:10.830: E/AndroidRuntime(30537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I want to convert above string in to float. What should i do or follow steps.

Please guide me with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Please show the value of `s1` and `s2`.  Put a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: @Simon : Let the value of s1 = 12 and s2 = 20.

Comment: this code must be worked, do Simon solution

Comment: i test your code with 12 and 20, result is 12.2, check your input

Comment: Agreed, this code works fine.  Debugging is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use

```
        String value = "25";
        String b = "1";
        String c = value.concat(".").concat(b);
        float f = Float.parseFloat(c);
        Log.d("message  :", "" + f);
```

Validation

```
EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
String s1 = ed1.getText().toString();
if(s1.length() <= 0)
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Value", 1000).show();
else
    // your task
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but getting same error. And i want to convert "12.12" string in float not only "12".

Comment: @Anit Bhatiya : Actually your suggetion is working is i enter value in edit text. But what to do for validation as what is i didnt enter any thing in edit text. Then now this code is giving error.

Comment: then u can put validation like check the length of edittext value

Comment: Thank you Anil. Your suggestions are really valuable.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText().toString()+"."+ed2.getText().toString());
```

Or this:

```
float f = Float.valueOf(ed1.getText().toString()+"."+ed2.getText().toString());
```